# Passing form object by reference

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

Hey! I've made a little boiler system that's controlled entirely by a form. The form components, however, call functions in a class for the boiler, radiators and so on.

I've got a little main class to that instantiates all of the classes but I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the form object to those classes so that they can access the form's components.

I guess I should be using mutator methods in each class to store the form object? How would I do this that's syntactically correct?

Thank you! ;o)

Comment: If it's not syntactically correct, it won't compile. Did you mean to use some other adjective like stylistically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the form to each `class`.  Store it in a private variable so the class can use it later.  It is passed by reference by default.

```
class Boiler {
   private Form parentForm;
   public Boiler(Form f) {
       parentForm = f;
   }
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a specific form type, e.g. <code>private OvenForm parentForm;</code>

Comment: Just to be picky - a *copy* of the reference is passed by value.  There is a subtle (yet important) difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a reference type to a method, C# (by default) will pass a copy of the reference to the method.  This means that if pass the reference you have to your classes you are giving the method a copy of that reference and since both copies reference the same object both the call site and the method will have access to the same instance.

For example:

```
class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "hello, world";
        // Here we are passing a copy of the reference
        // stored in "s" to "Print"
        Print(s);
    }
    static void Print(string str)
    {
        // By default, "str" will be assigned the copy of the 
        // reference passed to this method.
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

I would be careful building an application in which your domain objects (in your case, `Boiler`, `Radiator`, etc.) know about the UI layer that consumes them.  If you find that you need to pass a `Form` to one of these domain models you are probably doing something wrong. If you show us a small example of what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to help you come up with a more maintainable solution.

Comment: Hmm well there's quite a bit of code but conceptually the form has a load of buttons, timer and such on it and the buttons call the methods in the classes like "click button a on the radiator a part of the form to bleed(); the radiator" or "click button x on the boiler to switchOff(); the system" if that makes sense?

How would you do this if this isn't a maintainable OO solution?

Comment: What you have described sounds fine to me.  What isn't clear though is why you need to pass the form itself to any of these objects.

Comment: Hmm well it's a case of the Boiler.bleed(); method resetting timers and progress bars and altering text and what not. Is that an alright way of doing it?

Comment: Andrew I don't suppose you could take a look at me code could you please? I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and I need to understand what it is before I go insane haha ;o)